# Quran 14:5 Allah told Moses to remind them the days of Allah, what were those days of Allah, what was happening?

Tags: prophet-ibrahim

Muhsin Khan

And indeed We sent Musa (Moses) with Our Ayat (signs, proofs, and evidences) (saying): "Bring out your people from darkness into light, and make them remember the annals of Allah. Truly, therein are evidences, proofs and signs for every patient, thankful (person)."

Shakir

And certainly We sent Musa with Our communications, saying: Bring forth your people from utter darkness into light and remind them of the days of Allah; most surely there are signs in this for every patient, grateful one.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking some time to learn more about our model by taking the 2 min. [tour] and checking the [help].

Answer (score 1):

What was happening was that Allah (ﷻ), out of His Mercy, was aiding the Children of Israel through their troubles/hardships.

Specifically, Ibn Kathir  رحمه الله said it refers to the

> "favors and bounties which He bestowed on them when He delivered them from the grip of Fir`awn and his injustice, tyranny and brutality. This is when Allah delivered them from their enemy, made a passage for them through the sea, shaded them with clouds, sent down manna and quails for them, and other favors and bounties. Mujahid, Qatadah and several others said this" [[Tafsir Ibn Kathir]](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=2345&Itemid=69).